# Can't import datasets from sklearn

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, attributeerror

When I try to import any dataset from sklearn, an attribute error appears.

> AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'int'.
> `np.int` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `int`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `int` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. When replacing `np.int`, you may wish to use e.g. `np.int64` or `np.int32` to specify the precision. If you wish to review your current use, check the release note link for additional information.
> What can I do with that?

I've tryed to install another version of numpy, but it didn't help

Comment: What numpy and sklearn versions do you have? You can try upgrading sklearn or downgrading numpy `pip install "numpy<1.24.0"`. Github issue [here](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/issues/1280).

Comment: If you don't write any details, which pandas, numpy, Python version do you use, and maybe a code example that raises you the exception, then it seems to us, that you don't care enough to get a meaningful answer. The tags are good.